# \heading not defined in creating table using tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am using a template given to me by the department. You can see the full template [here.](https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template)

I have used a package called tabularx, and in overleaf I get following  error
[image: overleaf tabularx error]
I could not copy paste because many times doing Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V for error in overleaf I had cursor changing and I could not do a Ctrl+C , I could select the error by right click on touchpad and drag but when I do a right click to copy it did not give an option to copy to search in Google.

here the table code of latex 
thesis.tex file has following

```
\documentclass[twoside,mtp]{iiitg}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thechapter \ \ #1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ \ #1}}
\clearemptydoublepage
\input{texfiles/chapter2}
```

and in chapter 2 I have added this table

```
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
            \hline
            \heading{Alpha}     & \heading{Beta}     & \heading{Gamma}     \\ \hline
            0         & 2        & 4         \\ \hline
            1         & 3        & 5         \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
```

and as I could understand from the screenshot I posted above use of `\heading` is creating problems.
In the github link of thesis template I gave above in thesis.tex they have not used `\usepackage{tabularx}` but I have added this line in tex file and then in the chapter2 I am doing this table manipulation.
So in this case how can I get rid of these errors and warnings in this example.

Comment: Please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small compilable document with all your definitions and used (relevant) packages. It seems, that you not load `tabularx` package in document preamble. Your problem is not showed code fragment, but in your document preamble.

Comment: If you look at the error message, you will see that the command `\heading` is not defined. Comment out the first line of your tabular and see if the document compiles.

Comment: @Zarko in the question second last line I mentioned "but I have added this line in tex file and then in the chapter2 I am doing this table manipulation. " so I have included \usepackage{tabularx} in preamble.

Comment: Where you added is the wronag place. It should be loaded in document preamble. Where you define `\heading`?. Your code fragment work fine, if I define own `\heading`. So, problem is in part of your document hidden from us. Please (again)  provide a MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: I added the package in preamble at line number 49 in original file shared here  https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template/blob/master/thesis.tex  , in the original template in github they have not mentioned that line but I have added that line in my overleaf project file `\usepackage{tabularx}` at line 49.
As per my understanding in file thesis.tex ,may be this should be helpful and is the full. tex . I am not able to understand which portion is relevant to post here for the heading part from above github link.

Comment: Where is defined `heading`? This is error which your receive from compiler.

Comment: ok so you mean to say I should define heading some where in preamble but there are a lot of things like section,subsection and chapter headings if I define some thing heading then it might affect that I think. More over I do not know how to define heading for use in table.

Comment: If you use `thead` from `makcell` instread your not defined `heading` your code work fine: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
\hline
\thead{Alpha}   & \thead{Beta}  & \thead{Gamma} \\ \hline
0               & 2             & 4             \\ \hline
1               & 3             & 5             \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your example it does the desired thing I tested it. Also let me know how can I produce vertical lines in columns because in my table created vertical lines separating columns are not coming.

Comment: Error, which you mentioned  in question title is not caused by your code fragment. SO please consider to change it since it is misleading. Your error is clearly reported: `heading` is not defined.

Comment: In my opinion for users like me who may not be clear for how tabularx works they copy paste the error in google and search for answers so the title I set should be appropriate because that is what I was searching in Google when the error came. Or if you suggest another title I will edit. I am not an expert in latex packages or any documentation etc so I wrote it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

- If you receive error as you stated in your question title, means that you not load the `tabularx` package.
- If you leaded the `tabularx` package, than question title is misleading. Please, consider to change it accordingly.
- Error, showed in question is clearly reported: `\heading` is not defined. This means, that you need to define it somewhere, the best place for this is document preamble that can be used anywhere in the document.
- It is unknown, what you expect from this command, but I guessing that something like this:

[image]

which is produced by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
\hline
\thead{Alpha}   & \thead{Beta}  & \thead{Gamma} \\ \hline
0               & 2             & 4             \\ \hline
1               & 3             & 5             \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

where `thead` command is define in the `makecell` package`.

Finally, a general tip: load only those packages which you really need. Define new commands as few as possible.

**Addendum:** 
regarding vertical lines in table: many people here (including me) prefer tables without vertical lines. To our opinions they looks nicer and more "professional":

[image]

Above table is produced by:

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X X X }
    \toprule
\thead{Alpha}   & \thead{Beta}  & \thead{Gamma} \\ 
    \midrule
0               & 2             & 4             \\ 
1               & 3             & 5             \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer this is exactly what I was looking. I changed the title of question as suggested.

Comment: I used exactly the same code as you mentioned but some how vertical lines did not appear. Here is a screenshot of how it appears https://imgur.com/b72NpwU and to make sure preamble I did what you mentioned this screenshot of preamble https://imgur.com/AtH6FtU . In case you want to see any thing more then here https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template you can see original template. I have just added the lines which in this discussion you wrote as answer. So ideally I should have had a table with vertical lines.

Comment: I see that your crystall ball is working well! +1

Comment: @egreg, thank you! Today I have time to polish it (crystal ball) , but who knows if this will be sufficient for tomorrow :-)

Comment: @koeradoera,I'm not expert for Overleaf, however, i tested my MWE in it and result is the same as I show in my answer. Anyway, see addendum to my answer for table example without vertical lines.